# PlaneMesh missing mirrored property

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I am trying to create a [PlaneMesh](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-extras-planemesh.html) with the "mirrored" property of PlaneMesh set to true.

```
PlaneMesh {
 id: planeMeshID
 ...
 mirrored: true
}
```

intellisense did not kick in when trying to typw "mirrored", and at runtime I got the error:

"PlaneMesh.mirrored" is not available in Qt3D.Extras 2.0.

I checked the src code for qplanemesh.cpp(1) to see if "mirrored" was no longer supported, but according to documentation it should work fine.

Is there a a fix, short of reinstalling, you can suggest? :)

(1) Qt/5.11.1/Src/qt3d/src/extras/geometries/qplanemesh.cpp

Comment: Try to use the `Qt3D.Extras 2.9` revision for the `mirrored` property.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles, although the mirrored property is still underlined in red. But that is fine with me. Hava a good weekend :)